# How to send ajax response data from model and display in codeigniter views div id

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, response

I want to display data when window load by ajax into codeigniter view div.

Here is my code please find below and please help me.

**In my views.php**

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
$(window).load(function() 
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>colleges/index",       
       success: function(server_response
       {
           if(server_response == 'success')
           {
              $("#fillgrid").html(server_response); 
           } 
           else{
              alert('Not OKay');
           }
                      }
   });   //$.ajax ends here
});
</script>
```

**In my controller.php**

```
public function index()
{
   $list['college'] = $this->Colleges_model->get_all_college();     

   $this->load->view('header');
   $this->load->view('Colleges/all_colleges', $list);
   $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

**In my model.php**

```
public function get_all_college()
{   
   $this->db->order_by("id","DESC");
   $query = $this->db->get("tbl_colleges");

   return $query->result_array();        
}
```

Comment: You needn't to ajax to do this , you are aleady have $list['college'] .Only you have to echo $list['college'] in (div #fillgrid) in the view When You access the index it will be there

Answer (score 0):

First of all set ajax success function as

```
success: function(server_response)
```

close bracket after success variable.

In your controller:

```
$list['college'] = $this->Colleges_model->get_all_college(); 
$html = $this->load->view('Colleges/all_colleges', $list, TRUE);
echo $html;
```